# Apps Scripts - Mi función no es bien ejecutada por el onEdit()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Buen día comunidad, tengo un problema con mi código de `Apps Script`. Cuando ejecuto mi función desde el mismo entorno de `Apps Script` todo me ejecuta bien en la hoja de cálculo, pero cuando es puesto dentro de una función `onEdit()` ya no me ejecuta bien, el `if (valor===clienteActual){}`. Si lo pongo por encima del `if(tipoDeApuesta=='SIMPLE')`, este último `if` ya no es ejecutado por la función `onEdit()`, no se porque si se encuentran al mismo nivel de ejecución.  Este es mi código:

```
 function onEdit(){
      activarApuesta()
    }

    function hojaApuestasActiva(){
      var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var hojaApuestas=archivo.getSheetByName(Hoja1)
      return hojaApuestas
    }

    function activarApuesta(){
      let hojaApuestas=hojaApuestasActiva()
      let celdaActiva=hojaApuestas.getActiveCell()
      let filaActiva=celdaActiva.getRow()
      let columnaActiva=celdaActiva.getColumn()
      let valor=celdaActiva.getValue()
      let rangoTablaDeBusqueda='J4:K30'
      let tablaDeBusqueda=hojaApuestas.getRange(rangoTablaDeBusqueda).getValues()
      if(filaActiva>=9 && columnaActiva==6){
        let montoDeApuesta=celdaActiva.offset(0,-4).getValue()
        let casaARestar=celdaActiva.offset(0,-5).getValue()
        let riesgo=celdaActiva.offset(0,-1).getValue()
        let tipoDeApuesta=celdaActiva.offset(0,-3).getValue()
        if(tipoDeApuesta==='SIMPLE'){
          let nuevoMontoCasa=montoActual(casaARestar,tablaDeBusqueda)-montoDeApuesta
          insertarNuevoMonto(casaARestar,nuevoMontoCasa,tablaDeBusqueda,hojaApuestas)
        }
        if(valor===clienteActual){
          let nuevoMontoExchangue=montoActual(exchangue,tablaDeBusqueda)-riesgo
          insertarNuevoMonto(exchangue,nuevoMontoExchangue,tablaDeBusqueda,hojaApuestas)
        }else{
          let clienteExterno=SpreadsheetApp.openById(idClienteExterno)
          let hojaDeApuestasExt=clienteExterno.getSheetByName(Hoja1)
          let tablaDeBusquedaExt=hojaDeApuestasExt.getRange(rangoTablaDeBusqueda).getValues()
          let nuevoMontoExchangueExt=montoActual(exchangue,tablaDeBusquedaExt)-riesgo                           
insertarNuevoMonto(exchangue,nuevoMontoExchangueExt,tablaDeBusquedaExt,hojaDeApuestasExt)
         }
      }
    }
```